# Selenium C# :: Which file type can be used for object repository for better performance?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel, selenium-webdriver

I am creating an Automation Framework using Selenium C#, currently I am working on the object repository part. So I would like to know what all types of files I can use as the Object Repository.Currently I am thinking of using either XML or Excel but I am not sure which one is better performance wise, so can any of you share your views on this and also let me know if there are any other options.

I am planning to use XmlDocument for reading xml and oledb connection for reading excel.

Answer (score 0):

By Object repository i think you mean different elements, their locators and some other required attributes, because As far as i know selenium do not have concept of Object Repository inherently.

If so, you need to think about who is going to maintain this Repository,
with few thousand locators, rather than performance maintainability would be a major issue.

Also, think about making it isolated by implementing an interface, so in future if you decide to change implementation because of any issue, it will be not impact your framework.

And XML, Excel, text file(with any delimiter), a Database, json file are good contenders for this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Kavan. I am currently creating a Keyword Driven framework using selenium. My goal is to build a framework which could test any website without making any changes in the code. So I wanted to keep locators in a separate file so that we can use different object repositories for different sites. But as you mentioned maintainability will be a overhead, do you have any suggestions other than using a object repository to further reduce manual effort.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does not work with XML pages by default, as browsers do not show XML files as XML, but show its as converted to html files.

For the task I had used following code (its based on HTMLAgilityPack):

XmlActions.cs

```
namespace BotAgent.Ifrit.Core.Xml
{
    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    public partial class XmlActions
    {
        private HtmlDocument _xmlDoc;
        private HtmlNode _rootNode;
        public XmlActions()
        {
            _xmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            string pageSource = Brwsr.CurrPage.PageSource.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty);

            _xmlDoc.LoadHtml(pageSource);
            _rootNode = _xmlDoc.DocumentNode;
        }

        public NodeSingle Elmnt(string xpath)
        {
            Update();

            var currNode = _rootNode.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

            return new NodeSingle(currNode);
        }

        public NodesMultiple Elmnts(string xpath)
        {
            Update();

            var nodesGroup = _rootNode.SelectNodes(xpath);

            return new NodesMultiple(nodesGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

XmlActions.NodeSingle.cs

```
using System;

namespace BotAgent.Ifrit.Core.Xml
{
    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    partial class XmlActions
    {
        public class NodeSingle
        {
            private readonly HtmlNode _currNode;

            public string Text
            {
                get
                {
                    return CleanUpStringFromXml(_currNode.InnerText);
                }
            }

            public string TagName
            {
                get
                {
                    return _currNode.OriginalName;
                }
            }

            public string XmlInner
            {
                get
                {
                    return _currNode.InnerHtml;
                }
            }

            public string XmlOuter
            {
                get
                {
                    return _currNode.OuterHtml;
                }
            }

            public NodeSingle(HtmlNode currentNode)
            {
                _currNode = currentNode;
            }

            public bool Exist()
            {

                if (_currNode == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            public bool AttributesExist()
            {
                return _currNode.HasAttributes;
            }

            public bool AttributeExist(string attributeName)
            {
                if (_currNode.Attributes[attributeName] != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            public string AttributeValue(string attrName)
            {
                return _currNode.GetAttributeValue(attrName, string.Empty);
            }

            public bool HaveChildren()
            {
                var firstChildNode = _currNode.FirstChild;

                if (firstChildNode != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            public NodeSingle FirstChild()
            {
                HtmlNode node = null;
                try
                {
                    node = _currNode.ChildNodes[1];
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //// No need to throw exception, its normal if there are no child
                }


                return new NodeSingle(node);
            }

            public NodeSingle Parent()
            {
                return new NodeSingle(_currNode.ParentNode);
            }

            private string CleanUpStringFromXml(string xml)
            {
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(xml);
                var root = doc.DocumentNode;

                root.RemoveAllChildren();

                return root.OuterHtml.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XmlActions.NodesMultiple

```
namespace BotAgent.Ifrit.Core.Xml
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    partial class XmlActions
    {
        public class NodesMultiple
        {
            private readonly HtmlNodeCollection _nodesGroup;

            public int Count
            {
                get
                {
                    return _nodesGroup.Count;
                }
            }

            public NodesMultiple(HtmlNodeCollection nodesGroup)
            {
                this._nodesGroup = nodesGroup;
            }

            public NodeSingle GetElementByIndex(int index)
            {
                var singleNode = _nodesGroup.ElementAt(index);

                return new NodeSingle(singleNode);
            }

            public List<NodeSingle> GetAll()
            {
                return _nodesGroup.Select(node => new NodeSingle(node)).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had used my own framework code here, but this must not create problem for you to change it to clear selenium code.

After this you can create static XML var with browser instance and use like this:

```
bool isIdExist = Brwsr.Xml.Elem(".//div[1]").AttributeExist("id");
```

or

```
bool haveChild = Brwsr.Xml.Elem(".//div[1]").FirstChild().Exist;
```